# SHGetFileInfo returns null icon

Tags: winapi, icons

Trying to get an icon of a file type using [this code](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shgetfileinfo) code sample 2. But after calling the function, the `hIcon` member in the passed `SHFILEINFO` structure is still null. I tried to give him file extensions only, such as .xml, .pdf etc., maybe this is the problem. 
Note: i need the file type description too, so i can't use the managed `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: k, nice. searched in google and it not seem to be in direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it.
If you don't give him a full path, and want a file type icon, set the flag `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` in the `uFlags` parameter.